# how to load content in a div tag with the safest and securest way so that no hacking can be done

Tags: html

I have some code which goes something like this

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="content">
            Main content here
            </div>
</div>
```

Now in the same page I have

```
<div id="footer-wrapper">
 <div id="footer">
   <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

So when a user clicks on contact us s/he should be able to see the content in the above `div` which has `id=content`

And what I need is that the content of the `<div id='content'>` should not be visible by any other way, not even by view source.

Comment: "No hacking can be done" - what do you mean? Is there a list of conditions failing which hacking will be possible?

Comment: So, what is the fear of hacking here? You want to make the content of the first div upon click of the href below. And none should see it otherwise. Right?

Comment: yea right but i dont want to use jquery n stuff

Comment: I have updated the post from what I understood from you. Edit if incorrect.

Comment: no jQuery ? youll have many lines of code vs 1 line.

Comment: it is correct can u please tell me how can i achieve it?

Comment: @RoyiNamir using ajax is permitted but not jquery, javascript also will do ...

Comment: can any one help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

not related.

I think you are talking about anchors.

```
<a name="tips">Useful Tips Section</a>

<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
```

Comment: no dude i am not talking about anchors i want a link to be opened in a div tag say in lay man terms ... i have file called contacus.html which has some content now preserving the main pages structure that content of contactus.html should be loaded in to the div only like we do using frames

Comment: it wont be visible in the source view but it will be visible in the generated source view. ( dom)

Comment: i was trying using this 
http://w3schools.com/ajax/
but the contactus.html page opens in the same window but not in that div tag what i mean to say is the main page settings are lost and only the contents of the contactus.html are loaded

Comment: can any one help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to show some content on click of a link, and you do not want that the text be available without clicking the link, in that case, AJAX will be handy to fetch the text you wish to show.

*I am not yet convinced why one will require such a feature. You may elaborate more on the requirement and why part of it.*

**Why not simple hide?** If you hide something using CSS/Javascript, the text is actually available in the DOM, but just not visible. So it can be brought out using a view source or similar way.

**How will it work with AJAX?** On click of the link, you shall make a AJAX query to some page like GetContent?linkid=32 and you may also put some authentication on it so that no one can directly call up this page. Once the content comes, you can show it.